# Why does this query result in a boolean instead of a number?

Tags: mysql, pdo, count, boolean

I'm trying to print out the total rows of this query, and I don't understand why this query result in a boolean instead of the integer with the total rows.

```
$butacas = $this->pdo->query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM usuarios WHERE sala LIKE $nombreSala');
```

I've tried to use `rowCount()` but I get this error telling me that $butacas is not an object.

So, I've asked what type of element was $butacas, and it is a boolean:

```
$x = gettype($butacas); //boolean
```

I've tried doing `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM usuarios WHERE sala LIKE theNameoftheSala` at phpmyadmin and I get the result as a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting an error from MySQL, so `query()` returns `false`. You need to quote the string after `LIKE`. Also, you need to use double quotes around your PHP string, because variables are not expanded inside single quotes.

```
$butacas = $this->pdo->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM usuarios WHERE sala LIKE '$nombreSala'");
```

But it would be better to use `bindParam`:

```
$stmt = $this->pdo->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM usuarios WHERE sala LIKE :nombreSala');
$stmt->bindParam(':nombreSala', $nombreSala);
$stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score 2):

If a [PDO::query](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php) fails, it returns a boolean `false`. In your case, it seems to be failing as you need to qualify your string literals with quotes (`'`):

```
$butacas = $this->pdo->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM usuarios WHERE sala LIKE '$nombreSala'");
```